# How to stub self methods in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

I have a controller with the following code.

```
def apply
  file_id = params[:file_id]

  if file_id.nil? && params[:file].nil?
    render json: '"No resume was provided"', status: :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end

  if params[:job_id].nil?
    render json: '"Invalid data was posted"', status: :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end

  job = Job.find(params[:job_id]) if Job.exists?(params[:job_id])
  if job.nil?
    render json: '"Unable to locate job for application"', status: :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end

  if file_id.nil? || file_id.to_i == 0
    resume = ApiController.save_file job.owner
  else
    resume = UploadedFile.find(file_id)
  end

  resume.person = ApiController.save_person(job.owner)
  resume.save_by(job.owner)

  render json: '"successfully saved application"', status: 200
end

def self.save_file(owner)
  resume = UploadedFile.new
  resume.attachment = params[:file]
  resume.owner = owner
  unless resume.save_by(User.system)
    render json: '"There was an error uploading this file, please make sure the file type is an accepted file type."', status: :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end
  return resume
end

def self.save_person(owner)
  person = Person.new(apply_params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :zip))
  ...

  result = person.save_by(owner)

  unless result
    render json: '"Errors occurred while saving person."', status: :unprocessable_entity
    return
  end

  return person
end
```

I'm trying to test all 3 methods individually but since the apply method calls the save_file and save_person methods, I think I need to stub those when testing the apply method, right?  So, that led me to this code...

```
  describe 'apply' do

    before(:each) do
      @file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files/test-resume.txt'), 'plain/text')
      @fake_uploaded_file = UploadedFile.new
      @fake_job = Job.new
      @fake_job.id = 1
      @fake_person = Person.new
      allow(Job).to receive(:find).and_return(@fake_job)
      allow(Job).to receive(:exists?).and_return(true)
      allow(UploadedFile).to receive(:find).and_return(@fake_uploaded_file)
      allow(controller).to receive(:save_file).and_return(@fake_uploaded_file)
      allow(controller).to receive(:save_person).and_return(@fake_person)
    end

    it 'accepts an uploaded file and saves it' do
      post :apply, file: @file, job_id:1, format: :json
      expect(controller).to receive(:save_file)
    end
  end
```

When I try to run this test I get an error message that the ApiController does not implement: save_file  How can I properly test this apply method to stub out the save_file and save_person methods?  Thanks.

Comment: I think the Single Responsibility principle should come in to play here - the controller shouldn't be doing all these things and it makes it harder to test effectively. I would refactor these out into classes and test those classes individually. Edit: You would then stub out the classes in the controller test to only test the controller itself.

Comment: Yes, I think I definitely need to refactor this for SRP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save_file and save_person methods are class methods. so they should be stubbed like this.

```
allow(ApiController).to receive(:save_file).and_return(@fake_uploaded_file)
allow(ApiController).to receive(:save_person).and_return(@fake_person)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried allow_any_instance_of(ApiController) and allow(controller) but neither worked.  This one worked... or at least got me further through the call stack.